# In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have a peculiar situation. After I pay up for the transaction and before I receive the SKTransactionStatePurchased notification from App store, I close my application. After closing my application, I get this alert "Your purchase was successful". Now, it all happens in such a way that I couldn't call,

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

and I couldn't unlock the functionality because before processing the updated transaction, my app quits. It doesn't enter the background, I kill it. Now how do I deal with this particular situation. Even if the I try the purchase again, I get this message, This purchase has already been made but not downloaded. May be it's because I am not finishing the transaction. If I try calling restore transaction, I don't get the correct response for this unfinished transaction.

How to deal with this situation? It is different from apple automatically responding to unfinished queries. Here the app store responds and frees itself of it's duties but before I could unlock and deliver the functionality and finish the transaction, my app gets killed may be due to an incoming call or something.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do I restore such transactions?

Comment: "I close my application" - why ever would you do that?

Comment: That's because in real time it's possible that in interruption kills your application while this process is on. It's a testing technique.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, our app deals only with consumables, so this might not apply to you.

However, in cases where we couldn't successfully finish the transaction, our transactions are usually returned in the state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased on restarting the app. Then we simply do the finishTransaction and the universe is in balance once again.

Comment: My app is dealing in non consumables. Transactions that aren't successfully finished aren't getting an new response on relaunch in my case. I don't seem to understand why?

Comment: Can you please tell me why I get this message? "You have already purchased this In App purchase but it hasn't been downloaded."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means the transaction has not been finished yet. finishTransaction will fail, particularly when called outside of the context of paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: